# Lower Bound for Sum.

Tags: real-analysis, summation, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function, analytic-combinatorics

I want to find a lower bound for the sum
\begin{equation}
(1/2)^{2n} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} \left|1- (1+\delta)^k (1-\delta)^{2n-k} \right|
\end{equation}
where $n>1$, $0<\delta<1/4$.

If I drop the absolute value and let $k$ go from $0$ to $n$ Mathematica is 
able to deduce a closed form expression
\begin{equation}
\frac{4^{-n} \binom{2 n}{n+1} \left((\delta +1) \left(1-\delta ^2\right)^n \, _2F_1\left(1,1-n;n+2;\frac{\delta +1}{\delta -1}\right)+(\delta -1) \, _2F_1(1,1-n;n+2;-1)\right)}{1-\delta}
\end{equation}
where $F_1$ is the [Hypergeometric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) function.

**Question:**
Is there any way to deduce a simpler lower bound of the above expression ?
The hard part for me is to prove that
\begin{equation}
\frac{(\delta +1) \left(1-\delta ^2\right)^n}{1-\delta} \, 
_2F_1\left(1,1-n;n+2;\frac{\delta +1}{\delta -1}\right)- \, _2F_1(1,1-n;n+2;-1) \geq n\delta/ C 
\end{equation}
where $C>0$ is a constant.

**My attempt**

The first order Taylor Approximation for $\delta$ around $0$ for the expression $1- (1+\delta)^k (1-\delta)^{2n-k}$ is $2(n-k) \delta$.

Then the sum 
\begin{equation}
(1/2)^{2 n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{k} 2 (n-k) \delta = \delta\  2^{-2 n-1} (n+1) \binom{2 n}{n+1} \asymp \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }} \sqrt{n} \delta.
\end{equation}
This is exactly the lower bound I want to get, namely $\Omega(\sqrt{n} \delta)$, but I cannot find a formal argument at moment. 
My problem is that $2(n-k) \delta$ is not a lower bound for the expression $1- (1+\delta)^k (1-\delta)^{n-k}$.

Comment: Because of the exponential growth, for each fixed $\delta \in (0, \frac{1}{4})$ the sum is roughly $ ( (1+\delta)^2 / 2 )^{n+o(1)} $. But I guess what you you want is some asymptotics uniform both in $\delta$ and in $n$.

Comment: How do you get  $((1+\delta)^2/2)^n$ ? It seems to be too small...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop the absolute value, the sum equals $0,$ no matter what mathematica says, so this gives you absolutely nothing useful. Otherwise, the term inside absolute value (for very small $\delta$) is positive for $k> n,$ and negative otherwise. If you break up the sum in this way, you get a hypergeometric expression which mathematica can compute the serie of at zero.

**ADDENDUM**

Defining

```
dog[n_, x_] := (1/2)^(2 n) Sum[(1 - (1 + x)^k (1 - x)^(2 n - k)), {k, 
0, n - 1}]
```

And then evaluating `dog[n, x]` has no hypergeometrics.

Also:

```
 dog[n_, x_] := (1/2)^(2 n) Sum[Binomial[2 n, k] (1 - (1 + x)^k (1 - x)^(2 n - k)), {k, 0, n - 1}]

Series[dog[n, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

gives

$$2^{-2 n} n x \binom{2 n}{n}+O\left(x^2\right).$$

WHich is about $O(\sqrt{n})$ in $n.$

Comment: I drop the absolute value and let $k$ go from $0$ to $n$ not to $2n$.

Comment: @vkonton ah, ok. But then Series[] returns a perfectly reasonable power series.

Comment: I just don't know how to lower bound the difference $\left((\delta +1) \left(1-\delta ^2\right)^n \, _2F_1\left(1,1-n;n+2;\frac{\delta +1}{\delta -1}\right)+(\delta -1) \, _2F_1(1,1-n;n+2;-1)\right)$ that appears.

Comment: @vkonton See the addendum.

Comment: You're right but since you drop $\binom{2n}{k}$ you get a lower bound $\Omega( n^2 2^{-2n} \delta)$ which is tiny.

Comment: @vkonton True.What do you want the bound to depend on?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the lower bound for the whole thing should be $\Omega(n^{1/2} \delta)$

Comment: @vkonton See further.